# Is there a way to simulate a scrollViewDidScrollToBottom in UIScrollView?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uiscrollview, uitableview

I would like to make an *infinite scrolling* on a `UITableViewController`, I'm using the `scrollViewDidScroll:` method to check the contentOffset, however I'm not able to drill down an offset that would be **the bottom** of the ScrollView.

Any suggestions?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Assuming contentSize.height > bounds.size.height

```
if ( contentOffset.y >= contentSize.height - bounds.size.height ) { ... }
```