# How to enable a button after a user scrolls through text view

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios

I'mtrying to do something like this: First of all, on start up, the "accept" button is disabled, user must read through terms & conditions in text view area, then the accept button will be enabled.
Here is my code so far, can anyone give me some suggestions?

```
- (IBAction)acceptAction:(id)sender {
    if ([self.termConditionTextView scrollsToTop] == true) {
        [acceptButtonOutlet setEnabled:NO];
        [[[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Term & Condition" message:@"Please read term &    condition first. Thank you." delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"Back" otherButtonTitles:nil] show];
    } else {
        [acceptButtonOutlet setEnabled:YES];
    }
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When you create your button, set `myButton.enabled = NO`

Set the `UIScrollViewDelegate` for your scrollview.

Then implement the `scrollViewDidScroll` delegate function. In the function, check the content offset of your scrollview to see if the bottom has been reached. Something like this:

```
- (void)scrollViewDidScroll: (UIScrollView*)scrollView
{
    float scrollViewHeight = scrollView.frame.size.height;
    float scrollContentSizeHeight = scrollView.contentSize.height;
    float scrollOffset = scrollView.contentOffset.y;

    if (scrollOffset + scrollViewHeight == scrollContentSizeHeight)
    {
        myButton.enabled = YES;
    }
}
```

Comment: thx dima, i have another question, how do i put text such as long articles in to scrollview? i tried to use textfield without editable, but if i scale the textfield to fill the scrollview, it will become like "i only scoll textfield" instead of scolling scrollview...then - (void)scrollViewDidScroll will never be triggled....u got any suggestions? thx

Comment: The problem is how you are setting up the frame for your subview. The height of the frame of your textfield should be set to the height of the bounds of your scrollview. As a side note: You might just want to use a UITextView to do this. It inherits from UIScrollView already, and will do what you want it to do without having to deal with 2 more views.

Answer (score 2):

I would have the accept button at the bottom of a textview (below it), and wrap them both in a `UIScrollView`. The user in this case must scroll to the bottom to accept. Of course you are aware that no one reads the text anyway. It's the most simple way I've implemented such feature in the past.

Answer (score 0):

I think an `IBAction` is not enough. You need an `IBOutlet` pointing to your button, and when you first load the view, you set it to `disabled`. Then you can check whether your `scrollview` (or `tableview`, same deal) is at its bottom by implementing `UIScrollViewDelegate` protocol and something like this: [Is there a way to simulate a scrollViewDidScrollToBottom in UIScrollView?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3120793/is-there-a-way-to-simulate-a-scrollviewdidscrolltobottom-in-uiscrollview). When this happens, you change the button to `enabled`.